# Get the substring of the text by using SelectionStart

Tags: c#, winforms

I want to get the substring of the text in the RichTextBox of Windows Form when I move the cursor with arrows in the keyboard.

```
    private void richTextBox1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        string wholeText = richTextBox1.Text;
        if (wholeText.Length >0)
        {
            int positionBegin = richTextBox1.SelectionStart;
            SelectedText = wholeText.Substring(positionBegin);
        }
    }
```

But it is incorrect. For example, I typed the sentence:

> How are you doing?

I want to get the substring

> you doing?

There are two ways.

- One is from right to left, say I move the cursor to the end of the sentence, use left arrow to move and stop before the letter `y`. I got

`ou doing?`

- Or from the left to roght, say I move the cursor to the beginning of the sentence, use right arrow to move and stop before the letter `y`. I got

  `you doing?`

  The case one lacks the letter `y'. Case two added a white space before`y`.

I tried +1 or -1 to the index, but it generated "IndexOutOfRangeException". 
Anything wrong to use `SelectionStart`?

Comment: Use the KeyUp event instead since the SelectionStart position hasn't changed yet when you run your code.  Or the SelectionChanged event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use SelectionChanged event instead of KeyDown. I will return correct substring, also it will handle mouse selections.